# retrieving values from Vector in Eigen Solver

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using Eigen Solver. I am having trouble retrieving the values from Vectors/Matrix that I create. For example in the following code, I don't have an error but get a run time error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen\Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    Matrix3f A;
    Vector3f b;
    vector<float> c;
    A << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10;
    b << 3, 3, 4;
    cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
    cout << "Here is the vector b:\n" << b << endl;
    Vector3f x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        c[i] = x[i];
        cout << c[i] << " ";
    }

    //cout << "The solution is:\n" << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How do I retrieve the value in x to a variable of my choice (I need this as this will be a parameter in another function I wrote).

Comment: `but get a run time error` Is it a something secret? Can you share it?

Comment: The problem is that your `std::vector<float> c` was never resized to have size 3 (not a problem with Eigen, and one should see that from the source of the runtime error)

Comment: Use  `c.resize(b.size());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
vector<float> c(3);
```

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    c.push_back(x[i]);
    cout << c[i] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comment, the problem was that `c` was not resized before assigning values to it. Additionally, you actually don't need the `Eigen::Vector3f x`, but you can assign the result of the `.solve()` operation directly to a `Map` which points to the data of the `vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/QR>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Matrix3f A;
    Vector3f b;
    vector<float> c(A.cols());
    A << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10;
    b << 3, 3, 4;
    cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
    cout << "Here is the vector b:\n" << b << endl;
    Vector3f::Map(c.data()) = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);

    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i) std::cout << "c[" << i << "]=" << c[i] << '\n';
}
```